# What happened to the AvroRecord class in CDH 5?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, avro

I'm trying to use CDH 5 (Cloudera Hadoop Distribution) repositories in my pom.xml as described in [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html). But Maven complains about `AvroRecord` not found.

Here's the repository setting from my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And here's how I declare the dependency to Hadoop in my pom.xml (the exclusion part is about related to getting rid of the eror "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration's signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"):

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0-cdh5.2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

When I check the documentation for Hadoop, AvroRecord seems to exist:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro/AvroRecord.html

But when I check the source code of Cloudera for branch **cdh5-2.5.0_5.2.1**, it does not seem to exist:

https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/tree/cdh5-2.5.0_5.2.1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro

In other words, the following seems problematic with Cloudera version but seemed to work when I used the Hadoop repository:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.avro.AvroRecord;
```

How can I get the AvroRecord class when I use Cloudera Hadoop?

Comment: Is it in hadoop-common? There are other source trees for this module I think.

Comment: @SeanOwen another search returned [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.0.0-cdh4.0.1/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro/AvroRecord.java), showing `AvroRecord` class in `hadoop-common` in [2.0.0-cdh4.0.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.0.0-cdh4.0.1/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro/AvroRecord.java). Am I using the wrong dependency? Is it not in `hadoop-common` in Cloudera distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a minute to figure out. It's "not there" upstream too:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro

But this is because it's a generated class. The definition is here:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/test/avro/avroRecord.avsc
https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/cdh5-2.5.0_5.2.1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/test/avro/avroRecord.avsc

You're not finding it presumably because it's a test class too, not included in any distribution. What I'm slightly confused about is how it got into the main project javadoc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, indeed the main project javadoc was one factor that added to my confusion.